# How to make words in checkbox text to be link

Tags: android, android-widget

I have CheckBox in my app and text description have four words and I need to make last two words to be link and when click on last two words to open some URL. How to do this ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185590/1671626) is the exact answer to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a portion of a Checkbox's text clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184597/how-do-i-make-a-portion-of-a-checkboxs-text-clickable)

Answer (score 2):

checkbox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

```
    <string name="order_terms_and_condtions">text... <a href="link">Terms and conditions</a> ...text</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello i dont know any other way but i hv a trick use button and set last two word as text of button and on the click listener set url and open it.