# TextView Word OnClickListner

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview, onclicklistener

Can I set an onClickListener for every word in the TextView on Android? 
There are multiple lines in a textView can I add a listener to every word? 
What are the techniques that I could use?

Is it possible or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining which word is clicked in an android textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601139/determining-which-word-is-clicked-in-an-android-textview)

Comment: This might answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext