# How to add hyperlink for a substring in text of a checkbox in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

My code :

```
<CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
         android:text="I agree for terms and conditions"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

### Question

1. Here for the text `"I agree for terms and conditions"`, I want to
   add hyperlink for the text `"terms and conditions"`
2. How to achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a portion of a Checkbox's text clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184597/how-do-i-make-a-portion-of-a-checkboxs-text-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in res->values->string.xml file

`<string name="string_name"><a href=/"http://www.example.com">abc </a> and <a href=/"http://www.example2.com">xyz</a></string>`

**In Code**

TextView txt;

txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

**in xml file :**

android:text="@string/string_name"

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("click here");
Matcher m = p.matcher("for more info, click here");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean result = m.find();
while(result) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "some text which contains pattern to linkfy");
    result = m.find();
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String strWithLink = sb.toString();

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strWithLink));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished the same thing using a `Spannable` object and registering a different `ClickableSpan` object for each one. With the Spannable you have the possibility to *style* the aspect of the string you want to show (text color, foreground/background color etc)

Comment: Well I disagree with this solution as you may end up in having to support multiple languages for your application and that will force you write horrible size `if-else if-else` code.

Comment: No you wouldn't. I am doing my it, supporting six different languages and not using any *horrible size if-else-if* @Toochka

Answer (score 0):

In your activity/fragment you add the following:

```
checkBox.setText(
    Html.fromHtml(
        "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">I agree for terms and conditions</a> "));
```