# How Do I Block a CheckBox Pressed State When User Clicks a ClickableSpan Inside Of It?

Tags: android, android-checkbox, clickablespan

I had a need to have a `CheckBox` that contained an integrated clickable area to bring up another screen in the app. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166879/115145) works wonderfully:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);

ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // Prevent CheckBox state from being toggled when link is clicked
        widget.cancelPendingInputEvents();
        // Do action for link text...
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        // Show links with underlines (optional)
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    }
};

SpannableString linkText = new SpannableString("Link text");
linkText.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, linkText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
CharSequence cs = TextUtils.expandTemplate(
    "CheckBox text with link: ^1 , and after link", linkText);

checkBox.setText(cs);
// Finally, make links clickable
checkBox.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

...except that I am running into the same problem as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184597/how-do-i-make-a-portion-of-a-checkboxs-text-clickable#comment90733092_47166879). When the user clicks the `ClickableSpan`, while the click gets registered and handled by the span, the `CheckBox` also briefly goes into the pressed state. The box of the `CheckBox` behaves as though the user clicked it, though it does not toggle the actual checked state.

You can see the effect in this GIF — watch the actual box of the `CheckBox` on the left:

[image: CheckBox Animation]

I still want that pressed state when the user clicks on the rest of the `CheckBox`, so I do not want to try changing a background or something to eliminate the pressed state. Is there a way from the `ClickableSpan` to say "please do not transition to the checked state"?

Comment: I doubt you can do this. A CheckBox is basically just a TextView with a compound drawable and a boolean, so when you press anything drawn in it, you're pressing the whole View. Does it actually check it though, or just make it look like it's going to?

Comment: @TheWanderer: Just as you see in the GIF, you get the brief pressed state flash, but that's it. There is no actual transition to the checked state. Frankly, I would have expected `cancelPendingInputEvents()` to cover this, which is why I was wondering if there was something else that could be called from inside of `onClick()` that would address the pressed state.

Comment: You might be able to do `setClickable(false)` and then set it back to true.

Comment: No luck, but that was a good thing to try -- thanks!